# Anyone familiar with the error "fatal error: decrypt_error"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, encryption, fatal-error

I'm using dbeaver to connect to a postgres database. When I attempt to connect I get this

> "received fatal error: decrypt_error".

I've never seen this error before and am not too sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Versions of DBeaver, Postgres? Add as update to your question. My suspicion is that your client does not know about SCRAM passwords.

Comment: Is there a corresponding error in the db server's log file?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.